# Display all childs in Firebase Database (Web)

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

So I successfully displaying 1 database from my firebase using limitToLast function. [Here is the webpage look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gTFz.png)
Kinda curious **how to display all of my databases (all childs from selected parent)** from firebase console using javascript?

[List of my database in firebase that I want to display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wo1HR.png)
and here is my code below:

```js
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
  var order = firebase.database().ref("order");
  
  order.on("value", function(snapshot) {
     console.log(snapshot.val());
  }, function (error) {
     console.log("Error: " + error.code);
  });
  
  var submitOrder = function () {
  
  var orderId = $("#orderOrderId").val();
  var shipping = $("#orderShipping").val();
  var subtotal = $("#orderSubtotal").val();
  var total = $("#orderTotal").val();
  };
  
  order.limitToLast(1).on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
      order = childSnapshot.val();
      $("#orderId").html(order.orderId)
      $("#shipping").html(order.shipping)
      $("#subtotal").html(order.subtotal)
      $("#total").html(order.total)
      $("#link").attr("https://wishywashy-179b9.firebaseio.com/", order.link)
      });
```

```html
<html>
   <head>
     <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.3.0/firebase.js"></script>
     <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.js"></script>
     <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firebaseui/2.5.1/firebaseui.css" />
    <!-- <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js'></script> -->
    <!-- Load the jQuery library, which we'll use to manipulate HTML elements with Javascript. -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Load Bootstrap stylesheet, which will is CSS that makes everything prettier and also responsive (aka will work on all devices of all sizes). -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
      <!-- <script type = "text/javascript" src = "data.js"></script> -->
   <body>
     <script type = "text/javascript" src = "data.js"></script>
     <div class="container">
        <h1>Merchant Portal</h1>
        <h3>Order Lists</h3>
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Order ID</th>
              <th>Shipping Price</th>
              <th>Subtotal</th>
              <th>Total</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <!-- This is empty for now, but it will be filled out by an event handler in application.js with the most recent recommendation data from Firebase. -->
              <td id="orderId"></td>
              <td id="shipping"></td>
              <td id="subtotal"></td>
              <td id="total"></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>    
       </body>
       </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to generate a new `<tr>` for each order. A very simple way to do this is simply generate the DOM elements in your `on('child_added'` callback:

```
var table = document.querySelector("tbody");
order.on('child_added', function(childSnapshot) {
  order = childSnapshot.val();
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  tr.appendChild(createCell(order.orderId));
  tr.appendChild(createCell(order.shipping));
  tr.appendChild(createCell(order.subTotal));
  tr.appendChild(createCell(order.total));
  table.appendChild(tr);
});
```

As you can see, this code creates a new `<tr>` for each child/order, and populates that with simple [DOM methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node). It then adds the new `<tr>` to the table.

This code uses a simple helper function to handle the repetitious creating of `<td>` elements with a text node in them:

```
function createCell(text) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text));
    return td;
}
```